# How to solve Type Error : can't convert complex to float

Tags: python

```
##T in Fahrenheit, P in psia, gas FVF in bbl/cu.ft, gas viscosity in cP
import math
def GFVF(temp, pres, Gamma_G):
    Z= ZFACT(temp,pres,Gamma_G)
    T = TPC1(Gamma_G)
    P = PPC1(Gamma_G)
    return 0.0050035*Z*(T+459.69)/P

def GVISC(temp, pres, gamma_G):
    temp = temp + 459.67
    Mw = 28.964*gamma_G
    Bg = GFVF(temp, pres, gamma_G)
    Pg = 0.000007522*(Mw/Bg)
    K = ((9.379+0.01607*Mw)*(temp**1.5))/(209.2+19.26*Mw+temp)
    X = 3.448+(986.4/temp)+0.01009*Mw
    Y = 2.447 - 0.2224*X
    exponent = X*pow(Pg,Y)
    Ug = (10**(-4))*K*(math.exp(exponent))
    return Ug
```

When I run the function, I get an error at the last line: *"Cannot convert complex to float"*, although I'm using float numbers I don't know how to resolve this error. I'm trying to cast, but it's not working.

That's my main:

```
gamma_G=0.65
y1_zfactor=list()
y2_fvf=list()
y3_visc=list()
x_pressure=list()
temp=170
for p in range(1000,5200,200):
    pres = p
    z_factor_value=ZFACT(temp,pres,gamma_G)
    GFVF_value=GFVF(temp,pres,gamma_G)
    GVISC_value=GVISC(temp,pres,gamma_G)
    y1_zfactor.append(z_factor_value)
    y2_fvf.append(GFVF_value)
    y3_visc.append(GVISC_value)
    x_pressure.append(p)

data_zfactor = {
      "pressure": x_pressure,
      "z factor":y1_zfactor
    }

df_zfact = pd.DataFrame(data_zfactor)

print(df_zfact)
df_zfact.plot(kind='scatter',x='pressure',y='z factor')
plt.show()

data_gfvf = {
      "pressure": x_pressure,
      "FVF":y2_fvf
    }

df_gfvf = pd.DataFrame(data_gfvf)

print(df_gfvf)
df_gfvf.plot(kind='scatter',x='pressure',y='FVF')
plt.show()

data_gvisc = {
      "pressure": x_pressure,
      "Viscosity":y3_visc
    }

df_gvisc = pd.DataFrame(data_gvisc)

print(df_gvisc)
df_gvisc.plot(kind='scatter',x='pressure',y='Viscosity')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shows NameError  (name  'ZFACT' is not defined),  I don't know the function np.lib.scimath.power() helps you please check  :)

```
lib.scimath.power(x, p)

Return x to the power p, (x**p).

If x contains negative values, the output is converted to the complex domain
```